# Add yyyy-mm to excel output file name in R

Tags: r

I'm currently saving an excel file as `"Fin_report.xlsx"`, but I would like to incorporate the dates at which it was saved, too. It should look something like: `"Fin_report-yyyy-mm.xlsx"`

where `yyyy-mm` is the date of last month. For example, if today is 2018-03-01, then today's file should be saved as: `"Fin_report-2018-02.xlsx"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a mixture of changing the month of a date and inserting a string into another one.

I would do it like this using the `lubridate` library for dates and by writing my own function `last_month()`, that prints us the month from last month.

```r
library(lubridate)

# A small function that prints the date 
# of the last month in the YYYY-MM format
last_month <- function(d = today()) {
  day(d) <- 1
  month(d) <- month(d) - 1
  format(d, "%Y-%m")
}

# lets try it
last_month()
#> [1] "2018-02"


file <- "Fin_report.xlsx"

# replace the .xlsx with -YYYY-MM.xlsx
file2 <- gsub("\\.xlsx$", paste0("-", last_month(), ".xlsx"), file)

file2
#> [1] "Fin_report-2018-02.xlsx"
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... This is so helpful.
one small thing, I'm using "saveWorkbook" instead and it looks like this, could you please show me how can i adjust it for the last_month function 

saveWorkbook(wb, "mylink/Fin_report.xlsx", overwrite = FALSE)

Comment: `file <- paste0("Fin_report-", last_month())` and then save it using `saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = FALSE)`

Comment: I appreciate your help David...

Last thing, the file is saved perfectly but where do I add  'xlsx' to save it as excel file ?

Answer (score 0):

Using only base R, you can get the current time on your computer with `Sys.Date()`. You can 'reduce' one month using a cool feature of `seq()`, this will give you:

```
lastmonth <- seq(Sys.Date(), length=2, by="-1 months")[2]
# [1] "2018-02-01"
```

You can extract only the month and years using `format`:

```
format(lastmonth, "%Y-%m")
# [1] "2018-02"
```

Then you can use `paste0` to format a string as a filename:

```
filename <- paste0("Fin_report-", format(lastmonth, "%Y-%m"), ".xlsx")
filename 
# [1] "Fin_report-2018-02.xlsx"
```

Comment: This would give the current month, not the last month

Comment: I fixed it one second before your comment